# Ejecutar archivo .bat en el servidor

Tags: php

Tengo en mi servidor remoto un archivo `.bat` que se llama `pruebacopia.bat` para copias de seguridad y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma, en `PHP`, de ejecutar ese archivo desde mi ordenador.

He estado probando con la función `exec()` en modo local primero pero no me ejecuta el archivo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Copia de Seguridad AYE</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="copiaindex.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Copia">
    </form>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST["copia"])){
      echo exec('cmd /c C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\pruebaejecucion.bat');
    }

    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué parte de la sintaxis de `exec()` es la que no entiendes? ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora? ¿Qué ruta y nombre de archivo tiene el `.bat`? Para poder ayudarte mejor deberías leer [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Lo que me pasa es que nosé si desde la función `exec()` podría ejecutar un fichero `.bat` que tengo alojado en mi servidor

Comment: Si esa es la pregunta, entonces la respuesta es sí. Pero debes tener en cuenta que se ejecutará con los permisos del usuario con el que se ejecuta el servicio del servidor apache. Te redacto la respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia exacto. Nose como poner la sintaxis de `exec()`

Comment: ¿Qué te sale en el navegador y qué te sale en el log de error de apache? No estoy seguro de que tengas suficiente reputación para usar el chat,
 pero si puedes deberíamos [continuar el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88285/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-xerox-12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ejecutar procesos por lotes `.bat` en Windows debes hacerlo a través de la herramienta [`cmd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
echo exec('cmd /c <ruta>\archivo.bat');
echo exec('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c <ruta>\archivo.bat');
```

Puedes hacer uso de `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` o `%WinDir%\system32\cmd.exe` si tienes instalado Windows en una ruta diferente.

También puedes usar [`start`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start):

```
<?php
echo exec('start /B <ruta>\archivo.bat');
```

Edito: el autor de la pregunta ha editado su redacción para incluir mi solución, por lo que ya le funciona en el servidor. El nuevo problema está relacionado con ejecutar el mismo archivo bat en remoto desde su equipo de pruebas. En el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88285/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-xerox-12) está la discusión, las alternativas y las conclusiones.

Comment: Para la ruta del servidor, tendría que poner: \\ip_server\<ruta>?

Comment: No, debería ser una ruta local. Si es una ruta de red no funcionará porque por defecto los servicios corren con el usuario local [LocalService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localservice-account) que es válido en la misma máquina, no en remotas. Deberías cambiar el usuario con el que se ejecuta el servicio a un usuario de dominio, permitiendo así acceder a recursos remotos.

Comment: ¿Podrías responder a las preguntas que te hice inicialmente? ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora? ¿Qué ruta y nombre de archivo tiene el `.bat`? También me vendría bien que respondieras estas nuevas ya que veo que el `.bat` está alojado en una máquina remota: ¿ambas máquinas tienen el mismo sistema operativo? ¿están ambas máquinas metidas en dominio o son independientes?

Comment: Claro, el archivo `.bat` lo tengo alojado en una máquina remota, osea mi servidor. Lo que quiero es ejecutarlo desde mi pc a través de código `php`

Comment: La funcionalidad es poner un botón que al pulsarlo, ejecute la función `exec()`

Comment: Pues si respondes a las preguntas podré ayudarte.

Comment: Edito mi pregunta

Comment: No estoy seguro de que tengas suficiente reputación para usar el chat,
 pero si puedes deberíamos [continuar el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88285/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-xerox-12).